# NewRelic crashed with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: crash, exc-bad-access, newrelic

NewRelic v3.378 crashed EXC_BAD_ACCESS with following stack:

```
Queue : com.apple.root.default-priority
#0  0x000000018f5b01d0 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x0000000100192a58 in -[NRMAMetricSet addValue:forMetric:withScope:] at     /Users/jenkins/workspace/ios_build_master/NewRelicAgent/NRMAMetricSet.m:72
#2  0x0000000100192cc0 in -[NRMAMetricSet addValue:forMetric:] at /Users/jenkins/workspace/ios_build_master/NewRelicAgent/NRMAMetricSet.m:99
#3  0x00000001001589a8 in -[NRMASummaryMeasurementConsumer consumeMethodMeasurement:] at /Users/jenkins/workspace/ios_build_master/NewRelicAgent/MeasurementEngine/NRMASummaryMeasurementConsumer.m:56
#4  0x00000001001587ec in -[NRMASummaryMeasurementConsumer consumeMeasurement:] at /Users/jenkins/workspace/ios_build_master/NewRelicAgent/MeasurementEngine/NRMASummaryMeasurementConsumer.m:37
#5  0x0000000100160f84 in -[NRMAMeasurementConsumer consumeMeasurements:] at /Users/jenkins/workspace/ios_build_master/NewRelicAgent/MeasurementEngine/NRMAMeasurementConsumer.m:34
#6  0x00000001001673b8 in -[NRMAMeasurementPool broadcastMeasurements] at /Users/jenkins/workspace/ios_build_master/NewRelicAgent/MeasurementEngine/NRMAMeasurementPool.m:140
#7  0x000000010016bf2c in +[NRMAMeasurements process] at /Users/jenkins/workspace/ios_build_master/NewRelicAgent/MeasurementEngine/NRMAMeasurements.m:370
#8  0x0000000100176750 in -[NRMATaskQueue dequeue] at /Users/jenkins/workspace/ios_build_master/NewRelicAgent/NRMATaskQueue.m:148
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this bug a few weeks back in version 3.396. I recommend upgrading to the current version (3.406) because there have been a few other bug fixes since then. the new version can be downloaded here : https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/mobile-release-notes/ios-release-notes

Comment: Cool Thank you! Is there any way to subscribe to NewRelic updates?

Comment: You can use this URL in an RSS reader for updates to the iOS agent release notes: https://docs.newrelic.com/taxonomy/term/3161/feed